# Find matching type for one of multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables.

table_0

```
id | id_table_1 |id_table_2 | people_id
1        1           0        1
2        0           2        1
3        0           0        1
4        0           1        2
```

table_1

```
 id | machine| type
   1    bmw      1
   2    reno     1
     ....
```

table_2

```
  id | machine |type
   1   yamaha     2
   2   ducati     3 
   ....
```

table_3 (type)

```
      id | name
      1    auto
      2    bike
      3    sportbike
      ....
```

I want to make select query which can get this result

```
tabel_0.id | table_0.people_id  | machine(table_1 or table_2) |  type
    1                1                      bmw                  auto
    2                1                      ducati               sportbike
    3                1                       ""                    ""
```

Last time I asked this question, but without row type and now I have this code

```
    SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, 
       IFNULL(table_1.machine, table_2.machine) AS machine
FROM table_0 
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Please help to fix my query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the join to type work for either `table_1` or `table_2`:

```
select  t0.id
,       t0.people_id
,       coalesce(t1.machine, t2.machine) as machine
,       t3.name as type
from    table_0 t0
left join
        table_1 t1
on      t0.id_table_1 = t1.id
left join
        table_2 t2
on      t0.id_table_2 = t2.id
left join
        table_3 t3
on      t3.id in (t1.type, t2.type)
```

You could improve your design by giving tables real names instead of `table_1` and `table_2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT table_0.id, table_0.people_id, table_1.machine, table_2.machine , table_3.type
FROM table_0 
   JOIN table_1 ON table_0.id_table_1 = table_1.id 
   JOIN table_2 ON table_0.id_table_2 = table_2.id
   JOIN table_3 ON table_2.type = table_3.id
WHERE table_0.people_id = 1
```

Comment: You're only looking up the type for rows in table 2.  And using an inner join for both table 1 and 2 would surely fail to return any row